# Table of content in MS Word 2010

Tags: ms-word

I have a problem figuring this thing out. On other MS Word documents Heading 1 is in normal position (first in line left corner), but in this particular document it's ahead of Heading 2 & Heading 3. I just don't get it why & how I can fix it?[Crazy table of content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k93Ci.jpg)

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: knee-jerk, rather than helping out you write this. Thank you

Comment: I made a copy & paste from the rules, and that points you to the place where you'd actually get help. I'm sorry, we can't be more helpful to people here on StackOverflow that ask questions which are totally out of scope. It saddens me that you don't understand this simple concept of on- and off-topicness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short answer, since the topic could also be of interest to developers programming Word:

You need to look at the **TOC 1** style. It appears that a FirstLine indent has been set. If this is removed Toc level 1 should align left, same as the other levels.